# How to migrate the existing project from WatchOS 2 into WatchOS 3

Tags: watchos-2, watchos-3, xcode8-beta3

I have an existing WatchOS 2 app. I want to upgrade it and add some WatchOS 3 features, so I have installed Xcode 8 beta 3. My question is do I need to create another target for WatchOS 3 project or I can still keep working on the same WatchOS 2 target and add new WatchOS 3 features there with Xcode 8.

Answer (score 2):

Use same target but functions/code would need to be conditional:

```
#available(watchOS 3, *)
{
    // do some watchOS 3 stuff
}
#else
{
    // do some watchOS 2 stuff
}
#endif
```